# Table sort store whether ascending or descending?

Tags: javascript, variables, sorting

I have an external javascript file that has a function that will sort an array of data.  I want to have HTML links in my HTML file that sort the table by a particular column, and if a header link is pressed multiple times, it will toggle between ascending and descending sort orders.

What is the best way to toggle this setting?  I'm thinking of storing a bool javascript variable on the HTML side to tell whether or not to tell the javascript to sort by ascending or descending order, but I'd like to be able to keep all of the programming type logic in my javascript file.  Maybe I'm overlooking an even more simple way of doing this?

Any help would be apperciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would populate the HTML table from JavaScript, and have the type of sort (column and direction) held as variables. So you would just change the sort values, and re-run your script that populates the HTML table.

To trigger the change I would add click events to each of the column headers (after the HTML has been populated) that run a function. The function would determine if it is a new column to sort on (change column, set sort direction to default) or if it is the same column that is already sorted (just change the sort direction), and then re-populate the HTML again.

This is a type of MVC design.

Answer (score 0):

I would hope that you change some icon for which direction you sorted, so, you can just key off of that.

If up_arrow then sort in descending order

for example.

The problem with storing it in a variable is that you then have to keep track of that information, and it can make the design harder.

Comment: I would argue that getting information from something in the design is worse than storing a separate variable for it.  That's just my opinion, but it seems best to keep things separate.  Thanks for the suggestion, I hope I'm not being too much of a poo poo-er.

Comment: @sooprise - There are ways that you could lose variables, or lose track of the data, if you make mistakes. By going with what is displayed then that risk is removed.